# Joint Probability Distributions (Alice and Bob go on a date!)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Alice and Bob have their first date tonight, and they agreed to meet at a restaurant at a certain time.

**NOTATION:** $U(a,b)$ is the uniform distribution between $a$ and $b$, and $W(c)$ is the exponential distribution with mean $c$.

Alice, the punctual person she is, arrives $X_1$ hours after the agreed upon time, where $X_1 \in U(0,1)$.

Bob isn't that good at judging time, and arrives $X_2$ hours after the agreed upon time, where $X_2 \in U(t, 1+t), \ 0 \le t \le 1$

Both Alice and Bob are impatient, so they will leave some amount of time after they arrive.

Alice will leave exactly $Y_1$ hours after she arrives, where $Y_1 \in W(\mu_1)$.

Bob will leave exactly $Y_2$ hours after he arrives, where $Y_2 \in W(\mu_2)$.

If at any point in time both Alice and Bob are at the restaurant, they will have their date.

Find the probability, $Pr$, that Alice and Bob will have their date. $Pr = Pr(t, \mu_1, \mu_2)$, and if needed, $Pr$ can be piecewise-defined.

---

So, this problem is really weird. I've done some stuff with joint probability distributions before (years ago, really), but most of the problems I remember only had two random variables: $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. Here there are four different random variables and I don't know how to tackle the problem.

In the simple case where Alice and Bob each wait $0.1$ hours, what I would do is assume that Alice shows up at a certain time and find all the possible times Bob can show up. I'd then integrate over all possible times Alice can show up. For example, if $Y_1 = Y_2 = 1$, then:

$$Pr(t) = \int_{0}^{t+0.1} 0.1 + x - t \ dx + \int_{t+0.1}^{t+0.9} 0.2 \ dx + \int_{t+0.9}^{1} 1.1 - x - t \ dx, \ t \le 0.1$$

$$Pr(t) = \int_{0}^{t-0.1}0 \ dx + \int_{t-0.1}^{t+0.1} 0.1 + x - t \ dx + \int_{t+0.1}^{1} 0.2 \ dx, \ t \geq 0.1$$

(Note: for clarity, I *should* also be considering the case of $t \geq 0.9$, but I left that out when I was working up the problem. The idea is that you know which integrals are a problem (a bound less than zero or a bound greater than one), so you know which term to throw out. The point is that it's piecewise-defined, at the end of the day.)

In fact, this is easily generalizable to the case where both Alice and Bob wait the same *constant* amount. But what happens when the waiting times for Alice and Bob are their own random variables? I think there's an outer layer of integrals I'll need, but I don't intuitively see where it comes from.

Comment: I observe that Alice is considered to be "punctual" because she is expected to arrive 30 minutes late.  This is a very relaxed definition of "punctual."

Comment: @Michael: My favorite case is when both values of $\mu$ are low: not only is the "punctual" one arriving 30 minutes late, but she can't even wait a single minute for Bob to show up. No wonder it's their first date - I can't imagine they'll have a second.

Comment: Yes, neither one seems interested in actually meeting.  But Alice waits less time  if $\mu$ is high, since $Y \sim exp(\mu)$ means $E[Y]=1/\mu$.

Comment: ...you're right - this problem has such bad notation it tricked me into thinking $\mu$ was the expectation of the exponential distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they need to have a date is that the latest arrival is no later than the earliest departure, i.e. $\max(X_1,X_2) \le \min(X_1+Y_1, X_2 + Y_2)$.  For convenience, you might want to consider two cases, according to who arrives first.  For example, the probability that Alice arrives first and they have a date is the probability that $X_1 \le X_2 \le X_1 + Y_1$.
You can get this as
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} dx_1 \int_{x_1}^{\infty} dx_2 \int_{x_2-x_1}^{\infty} dy_1 \; f_{X_1,X_2,Y_1}(x_1,x_2,y_1) $$
where $f_{X_1,X_2,Y_1}$ is the joint density of $X_1,X_2,Y_1$ (but watch out for the intervals where the density is $0$).

Comment: Hm, that's an easier way to look at it. Maybe I'm just rusty, but how do I get the joint density of $X_1, X_2, Y_1$? Do I just, at each point from $0$ to $\infty$, multiply the corresponding value of the pdf for each of them together?

Comment: They are independent, so the joint density is the product of the densities.

Comment: I see, and the only reason we "really" have to integrate to $\infty$ is because we have an exponential distribution for $Y_1$, right? If $Y_1$ were more tame, like some discrete probability distribution, we could get away with integrating up until $max(X_1 + Y_1)$, correct?

Comment: Just as an update: this method gave exactly the answer desired. Thank you! (: